# Is render() is required when using Interceptors?

Tags: grails, groovy

This appears to go against the "convention" nature of Grails.  If I don't explicitly call the `render()` method with my view, then the service injection in my Interceptor is null.

Interceptor:

```
class GlobalParamsInterceptor {
def SysConfigService sysConfigService;

GlobalParamsInterceptor() {
    matchAll();
}
boolean before() {
    true
}

boolean after() {
    model.isApplicationOpen = sysConfigService.isApplicationOpen();

    true
}

void afterView() {
    // no-op
}
}
```

Controller:

```
class ConfigController {
static namespace = "coordinator";

def index() {
    render(view: "index");
}
}
```

If I comment out `render(view: "index")` in my controller then `sysConfigService` in my Interceptor is `null`, otherwise it works great.  Can someone please explain why that is?

Edit:
Grails 3.1.3

Edit #2
It appears i was mistaken, the `sysConfigService` is not null...its the model that is null so I am unable to set the `isApplicationOpen` property on it.  Just the same though, I don't believe I should have to call the `render()` method in order to access the model as I thought that was an inherited property from the framework.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?  I just tried unsuccessfully to reproduce in 3.1.2.  As a general rule, specifying the version is a Good Idea.

Comment: @mmigdol my bad, i updated my post.  Version 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I comment out render(view: "index") in my controller then
>   sysConfigService in my Interceptor is null, otherwise it works great.

I don't think think that is possible.  The dependency injection into your interceptor happens and is completed before any requests can ever enter the application.  Invoking `render` (or anything else) in a controller action can't affect that.

Also, you have `def SysConfigService sysConfigService`.  The `def` there is superfluous.  You can delete it and the compiler will generate the same code.  `def` is only sensible there if you remove `SysConfigService`.

EDIT:

I realized after posting that that I did not address the question in the title:

> Is render() is required when using Interceptors?

The answer is "no".

> In your example though, your calling render from your controller. My
>   issue is that If I don't call render and rely on the "convention" of
>   Grails to auto detect my "index.gsp" instead, that is when model in my
>   interceptor is NULL.

See the commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/raymond/commit/f354047158038f571630ab7e3e0416850bdde8a8.

When I send a request to `/demo/report` I see the following output on stdout:

```
Model: [name:Raymond]
```

That output is coming from https://github.com/jeffbrown/raymond/blob/f354047158038f571630ab7e3e0416850bdde8a8/grails-app/controllers/demo/FooInterceptor.groovy#L13.

Comment: Maybe something inside of your `isApplicationOpen()` method or something that it calls is null.  That is plausible, depending on what that method is doing.

Comment: unfortunately it seems it is possible because its happening to me.  This is practically a new project so there isn't really anything else that could be interfering.  And yes I am sure its the `sysConfigService` that is null.  The error I get is that `.isApplicationOpen()` isn't valid for a null object.  I updated the post with my Grails version in case that helps.  3.1.3

Comment: Jeff, it appears you were right and I read the error message wrong.  When I ran this through the debugger its actually the `model` that is NULL.  I was setting a properly called `isApplicationOpen` which matches the service method.  Still though, the `model` shouldn't be null should it?

Comment: "Still though, the model shouldn't be null should it?" - No, it shouldn't be null.  When the action at https://github.com/jeffbrown/raymond/blob/1987c71af8a4771af8d619373f9e692f4b75a748/grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy#L6 is invoked, the `model` at https://github.com/jeffbrown/raymond/blob/1987c71af8a4771af8d619373f9e692f4b75a748/grails-app/controllers/demo/FooInterceptor.groovy#L13 is not null.

Comment: In your example though, your calling `render` from your controller.  My issue is that If I don't call `render` and rely on the "convention" of Grails to auto detect my "index.gsp" instead, that is when `model` in my interceptor is NULL.

Comment: I have responded to your comment in the answer.

Comment: In an attempt to help you I have taken the time to create a sample app to demonstrate that what you original reported isn't happening and later spent more time updating the sample app to address another claim that you made. If you were to take time to provide a similar app which demonstrates the problem, that would save other people's time.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts.  I will accept your answer because I am probably dong something wrong and your demo does work.  I actually prefer explicitly calling the render anyways as it makes the code easier to follow.